# CodeIgniter Error opening Home Page

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I create a Home Page and when I want to access it's written **Page Not Founded**
I create in my rount.php access but again there is same error

```
$route['pages/index']= 'pages/home';
```

Do I need to change my controller or model or just route.php file

**Pages controller**

```
<?php

class Pages extends CI_Controller{

    public function index(){

        $this->load->view('pages/home');
    }

    public function view($page='home'){
        if(!file_exists(APPPATH. 'views/pages/'.$page.'.php')){
            show_404();
        }

        $data['title']= ucfirst($page);


        $this->load->view('templates/header');
        $this->load->view('pages/'.$page,$data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    } 
}
```

Comment: you should call as pages/home in url

Comment: I changed, but again same problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try like this . and make sure you are linking right base_url for home index function like this. follow this if its help .

```
echo base_url("pages/home");

$route['pages/home']= 'pages/index';
```